# Spacing problem after long leg n

Tags: beamer, tipa

[image]

Why the words after the long leg n appear in the next line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\newcommand{\mathnrleg}{\textnormal{\textnrleg}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textcolor{blue}{\underline {Likelihood Ratio Method}}
\begin{itemize}
\item For a scalar parameter of interest $\theta$, the likelihood ratio statistic for testing the null hypothesis, $\text{H}_0$: $\theta$= $\theta_0$ versus $\text{H}_1$: $\theta$ $\neq$ $\theta_0$ is given as,\\
\vspace{-3mm}
\[
\Psi=2[l(\hat{\theta},\hat{\mathnrleg})-l(\theta_0, \tilde{\mathnrleg})]
\]\\
{where $l$ is the log likelihood function,\\
\mathnrleg is the vector of nuisance parameters,\\
($\hat{\theta}$,$\hat{\mathnrleg}$) is the maximum likelihood estimator of($\theta$,$\mathnrleg$),\\
$\tilde{\mathnrleg}$ is the restricted maximum likelihood estimator of  $\mathnrleg$ under $\text {H}_0.$}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can't reproduce the error.  the mwe provided doesn't produce line breaks after the `\mathnrleg`.  (using tex live 2016/)

Comment: `($\theta$,$\mathnrleg$)` is not correct, see in my solution.

Comment: How are you compiling? Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: i realised the line break only occur when i run my complete slide. if i only run the part i provided here, the line breaks doesnt occur.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\newcommand{\mathnrleg}{\text{\textnrleg}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}{}
\begin{block}{Likelihood Ratio Method}
For a scalar parameter of interest $\theta$, the likelihood ratio
statistic for testing the null hypothesis, 
$\text{H}_0\colon\theta=\theta_0$ versus 
$\text{H}_1\colon\theta\neq\theta_0$ is given as,
\[
\Psi=2[l(\hat{\theta},\hat{\mathnrleg})-l(\theta_0,\tilde{\mathnrleg})]
\]
where 
\begin{itemize}
\item $l$ is the log likelihood function,
\item $\mathnrleg$ is the vector of nuisance parameters,
\item $(\hat{\theta},\hat{\mathnrleg})$ is the maximum likelihood 
estimator of $(\theta,\mathnrleg)$,
\item $\tilde{\mathnrleg}$ is the restricted maximum likelihood estimator
of  $\mathnrleg$ under $\text{H}_0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should also be `\mathrm{H}` rather than `\text{H}`.

Comment: any difference  between this two? i got the same output

Comment: thanks for the suggested solution. this solution doesn't produce the line breaks i got before this.

Comment: @yap `\mathrm{H}` generates roman font; `\text{H}` does default font. In this case the default is the roman.